# How to escape double quote character in Oracle identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to escape double quote character in Oracle identifier?

This doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE "foo""bar" ("xxx" CHAR(1))
```

Comment: Why would you want quotes inside of a table name? That's just asking for trouble, even if there is a way.

Comment: Additionally: using quoted identifiers in general is not a good idea.

Comment: It is for general purpose ORM solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I escape double quotes in column titles with Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500872/can-i-escape-double-quotes-in-column-titles-with-oracle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It is not possible](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm):

> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).