# Can I escape double quotes in column titles with Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, header, escaping

Creating a table with a double quote to escape the real double quote doesn't seem to work in Oracle's SQL syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTable" (
"Col""umn 1" varchar(168)
);
```

The above fails. Is there any way to escape the double quote to make 'Col"umn 1'?

Comment: I guess we can't create a column name containing `"`.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? I can see no good reason for this unless you despise everyone who will have to query this table!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name he wants to have problem, I think `:D`

Comment: I don't want to, but others might.

Comment: @Dan W is your plan to allow other users to dynamically create tables with unspecified names? If so, you will have to tightly control the characters allowed in the table names.

Comment: Yes, if by 'unspecified', you mean 'they decide the names, I don't'. Apparently, table names can have any chars apart from <null> and " according to the answer below as long as they're quoted identifiers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not.
According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm):

> Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from
>   your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($),
>   and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and
>   "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in
>   nonquoted identifiers.
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks
>   as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers
>   can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

Comment: The impossibility of using quotes (I mean ASCII 34, not Unicode flavors) in identifier can actually be utilized for one's good in some cases. For example if you maintain some metadata-like system where function parameter names and also return value is stored, you can register return value under auxiliar name which contains quotes, such as `"return"`. Then you can be sure attacker cannot crash system creating function with confusing parameter like `""return""` because Oracle disallow her doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could, of course, use unicode!

```
SELECT
    1 "“Unicode Rocks”",
    2 "ʺSooo cooolʺ",
    3 "＂My co-workers love me＂"
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help... But please DO NOT create tables with such columns:

```
CREATE TABLE DropMe AS
SELECT rpad('X', 168, ' ') "Col''umn1" FROM dual
/

SELECT * FROM DropMe
/

SQL>

Col"umn1
-------------------------------------.....
X
```

Comment: This produces two apostrophes instead of quotes (ASCII code 34): can be easily verified by query
`select length(column_name) from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'DROPME'` (results 9) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* create columns with double quotation marks, despite what the documentation claims. This is probably a bug based on the way Oracle automatically names unaliased expressions from inline views.

```
SQL> create table "MyTable" as
  2  select * from (select 'Col""umn 1' from dual where 1 = 0);

Table created.

SQL> insert into "MyTable" values ('A');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from "MyTable";

'COL""UMN1
----------
A

1 row selected.

SQL>
```

But you do *not* want to create such columns because they are broken for several reasons. While a `SELECT *` will work, there is no way to directly reference the column as far as I can tell. And the column name isn't even precisely what was specified - notice the extra single quotation mark and the missing space from the column name. If you create a view on the table, the view will be created but cannot be referenced. And there are probably many other bugs related to such a broken column name.

If you find yourself in this situation, you can't even alter the table to fix the name; you'll need to drop and recreate the table.